# TextInput gets unfocused after typing each character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, parent-child

I'm using React to build a form and I'm trying to filter a `list` with the `SearchInput` (which works the same as TextInput) located in the child component `Header`. But everytime I type a character the SearchInput gets unfocused

```
function index() {
  const list = [//data\\]
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);

  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearch(searchValue);
    if (search !== "") {
      const filteredData = partners.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item)
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(search.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(partners);
    }
  };

  const Header = () => (
    <Box>
      <SearchInput
        placeholder="Search"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <Parent
      headerContent={<Header />}
    >
      <Box>
        <Table data={search.length > 1 ? filteredResults : list} />
      </Box>
    </Parent>
  );
}

export default index;
```

Comment: At a glance that code looks ok - where is SearchInput from? Is that your component or a 3rd-party thing?

Comment: I've tried to change location to it, and insert it above the Table component, and it works fine there, so I don't think the SeachInput is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I think I can see the problem now - it's the way you're rendering the `<SearchInput />` component. You're inadvertantly creating a new functional component on every render. Either inline the `Header` directly into the `Parent` control's `headerContent` property, or create an entirely separate component:

```
const Header = ({ search, onSearchChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => onSearchChange(e.target.value);
  
  return (
    <Box>
      <SearchInput
        placeholder="Search"
        value={search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

function index() {
  // ----- 8< -----
  return (
    <Parent
      headerContent={<Header search={search} onSearchChange={searchItems} />}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

While you're there, you have a subtle bug with your comparison - it looks like you're searching your `partners` effectively as a list of strings; but, since you're joining them, if you had partners with the names:

```
'one'
'two'
```

You're creating a search string as 'onetwo' - so searching for 'et' would match, even though you don't actually have a partner matching that. You can fix that by just checking each partner individually... something like:

```js
const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
  setSearch(searchValue);
  
  if (search !== "") {
    const searchValueLower = searchValue.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = partners.filter((item) => {
      return Object.values(item)
        .some(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValueLower);
    });
    
    setFilteredResults(filteredData);
  } else {
    setFilteredResults(partners);
  }
};
```

Comment: Although it's a good answer, I still have the same problem

Comment: In that case I'm not sure without seeing more of your code. Can you reproduce the issue in a CodeSandbox?